# L298N shield gives relatively low ouput voltage and current

Tags: motor, l298

I am using a L298N shield together with an Arduino to drive a 42mm 2 phases bipolar stepper motor. The driving voltage for the motor is 12V and the logic voltage for Arduino and the L298N shield is 5V.

Everything seems work fine, the stepper motor moves under control without losing steps. However, when I try to measure the voltage across and current through one phase of the stepper motor, I find that the voltage is just about 2.4V and the current is just about 0.075A, which is far from the specified phase voltage and current rating (12V, 0.4A / phase) of the motor.

I want to know that is this a normal case for a L298N shield? Does the L298N have a relatively low efficiency?

If I increase the driving voltage for the motor to 24V / 36V, would this help to increase the output voltage of the L298N shield? But would this put the L298N to a even lower efficiency?

Are there better ways to put higher voltage and current to a stepper motor?

Comment: Please share the schematic of how you have the motor wired up, and ideally also a link to the specific shield device you are using. At first glance, it appears that the L298N is not connected properly for driving a bipolar stepper: Please refer to Figure 8 of the [datasheet](http://www.tech.dmu.ac.uk/~mgongora/Resources/L298N.pdf) and check that that's how the shield + motor connection is set up.

Comment: If the L298 is running in chopping mode and you are measuring it with a meter rather than a scope, the problem may be primarily in the measurement.  However, a "12v" motor will have poor torque at higher step rates as it has a high winding resistance and thus high inductance which will severely limit the current that can be driven at high step rates.  Modern setups generally prefer low voltage windings, driven from much higher supplies using chopping current regulation to keep things within spec.

Comment: @Anindo I bought my L298N shield from a chinese taobao shop [here](http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=12224321561). The Arduino pins 8,9,10,11 are connected to IN1,IN2,IN3,IN4 of the L298N. I just control the Arduino pins to drive the OUT1/OUT2 and OUT3/OUT4 outputs of the L298N alternatively to control the stepper motor. It's just a simple control.

Comment: @user1129812 Going by the google-translated page for the product, and the schematics, it appears that the connections are right. The L298 does not have a low efficiency, so ChrisStratton's comment might be worth looking into. How are you measuring current / voltage?

Comment: @Chris I think I am not running the L298N in chopping mode (there is no L297 there). I have not driven the stepper motor in a fast rate, I have used about 8 milliseconds for each driving step (e.g. 8ms for A+ to B+) and I think that this timing scheme has allowed enough time for the phase current to reach its maximum value. For my measurement, I just used normal procedure to measure voltage and current, but I am not very sure such procedures would/would'nt affect the measurement result.

Comment: @Anindo For my measurement, I have put IN1/IN2 of L298N to a HIGH/LOW state and left IN3/IN4 both to LOW state to lock the stepper motor in a certain position. I then measure the voltage across and current through OUT1/OUT2 of the L298N to get my measurement results. I think this measurement gives the conditions for one phase of the stepper motor.

Comment: @user1129812 What you are measuring then is current at rest position of the stepper - which is necessarily lower than during rotation. Steppers consume very little power when holding a full-step position (not a microstep). In fact, once a position is achieved, you can actually power down the motor, holding torque will keep it in position against minor perturbations.

Comment: @Anindo For my understanding, I think, at rest position, the stepper would draw its largest current as the voltage is held fix there for enough time for the phase coil to reach its maximum current. If the stepper is rotating, the voltage across a phase would not be held long and so the phase current may not reach its highest value. So I think the phase current at rest position may represent the highest current through the 2 phase coils (there is no current limiting components in my circuit), but the measured small maximum current means that the stepper may not be fully utilized.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - No.  What you propose would only be the case with a driver sophisticated enough to back off the current in rest state, which is not the case here.

Comment: As a 12V/3.5A power is supplied to the L298N shield and assuming that the 12V driving voltage reaches the Vs pin of the L298N, I expect the output voltage across OUT1/OUT2 and OUT3/OUT4 of the L298N to be not far away from 12V. But, assuming my method of measuring phase voltage and current is correct, the maximum output power is just 2.4V * 0.075A = 0.18W per phase. Although the stepper motor is nearly hardly stopped by my fingers even at this relatively low output power, I suspect that the motor would perform much better at a higher output power. That's the point that I am insisting on.

Comment: After some testing, I now suspect that there may be some cheating in the L298N shield. I find that even if I do NOT supply any motor driving voltage to VCC of the shield (i.e. only supply 5V to the "5V" connector, my stepper motor runs smoothly and the measured phase voltage is again about 2.4V. This seems mean that the shield is in fact supplying 5V to Vs of the L298N and is not using the VCC driving voltage. I may later ask the vendor whether the VCC voltage could be used. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: After some more testing, I now find that I have a mis-use of the power pin of the L298N Shield and a connector from my power supply to the L298N Shield is faulty. I should just connect VCC/GND in the Shield to the driving voltage, the 5V pin could be left unconnected. However, the faulty connector from my power supply to the L298N shield causes me so much trouble. It has bad solder points inside and it causes the driving voltage to drop when current is draw. I never have this experience before and it teaches me a lesson. My L298N is now working properly and smoothly.